# Wordpress Posts in different Columns

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Usually I try to figure out things myself, but I'm stuck here and couldn't find a solution for this on the Internet. I try to figure out/know if there is a possibility to have an option in wordpress in which column I want a post ( it's thumbnail ) to be posted in. Let's say I have 5 Columns on the Index site, and I want certain posts only to be posted in Column 1.

The reason I try to do this is to have an more fluent look of the thumbnails. I know Isotope would be an option but since I have fixed widths which causes the order of the thumbnails to be mixed up, I tried to find a different solution.

Comment: This question seems theme specific.  Please elaborate...

Comment: I would do this from scratch. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough with my question. Just wanted to know if it's possible. Right now the only function I have is to post a thumbnail and post title in a column, that's it. What I try to have is just an option so I can say "i want post X in the index overview to be in Column1 and post Y in Column2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. [Two loops.](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_1) The first loop would populate column 1, and the second would populate elsewhere.
2. If the columns are populated sequentially, you possibly could populate column 1 and then column 2 in the same loop.

   ```
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       $column1 = 0
       if ($column1 < 2) {
          //code to populate column 1
       }
       else
          //code to populate column 2
       }
   endwhile
   ```

Comment: Not sure what I did here. The code isn't formatting correctly even though it's indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, I will try what you suggested and google a bit for this, and give you feedback on it.